# Jetty: Client closes TCP connection before receiving a response from a request

Tags: java, iis, jetty

I am trying to make a POST request to a Microsoft IIS Webserver (5.1) using the Jetty Client (v9). However this will result in an EOFException on the client-side. After some investigation with wireshark I found that the TCP connection is closed by the client immediately after the request is sent and before a response is arrived.

If I am making the same request to a Tomcat-Server, it works perfectly.

Does someone know this issue or what could lead to it? Bug in Jetty?

Client:

```
if (jettyClient != null) {
        if (jettyClient.isStarted()) {
            remoteHostname = httpAddress.getRemoteUrl().substring(7);
            serviceURI = httpAddress.getRemoteService();
            logger.debug("post an: " + httpAddress.getRemoteUrlPortService());
            Request request = jettyClient.POST(httpAddress.getRemoteUrlPortService());

            request.version(httpVersion);
            request.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, httpContentType);
            request.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(msg.length()));
            request.header(HttpHeader.HOST, remoteHostname + ":" + httpAddress.getRemotePort());
            request.timeout(httpTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // 20000
            request.agent(ApplicationMeta.name + " " + ApplicationMeta.version);
            request.method(HttpMethod.POST);
            request.header("SOAPAction", soapAction);


            request.content(new StringContentProvider(msg));

            HTTPIncomingResponseSet set = null;

            try {
                ContentResponse response = request.send();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
              // ....
            }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should post a working example for this? This cannot be decided on the information you provide.

Comment: `HttpClient` does not close connections unless explicitly told to do so, or because of a timeout (which is unlikely given it has just sent a request). The fact that changing the server the behaviour is different seems to suggest that is a server problem, so perhaps it's the server that initiates the connection close (perhaps an authentication problem ?).